# Counting Matrices

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

How does one count the number of binary $n\times n$ matrices which are such that each row has $k$ 1's and each column also has $k$ ones?

Comment: This is closely related to the question you posted and deleted yesterday about Connect-4.  Is there a general problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes this one, I thought stating it like this would make it clearer.

Comment: I believe this can be converted to block designs, although it has been too many years since I have studied them for me to think how.

Comment: For $k=2$ see [A001499](https://oeis.org/A001499)

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks!